# What is the difference between "summation" and "sum"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Are these sentences grammatically right? which one is more formal? It seems to me that the first group is more convenient, am I right?

Can I say these sentences in other way or in a better format?

a)

> The total potential energy of the cylinder is the "summation" of the strain energy and the work done by the external forces.
>
> A is the "summation" of B and C.

b)

> The total potential energy of the cylinder is the "sum" of the strain energy and the work done by the external forces.
>
> A is the "sum" of B and C.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need ''summation" when you mean "sum"? The fact is that "sum" is the result of summation, which is a process, though it is used in some contexts to emphasize its nature. Please see a good dictionary.

Comment: Use 'sum'. 'Summation' is overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would be understood, but b) would be more correct.  The summation is the act of adding the values; the sum is the result of it.

Comment: what is your suggestion for revising these sentences?

Comment: I'd say use b), those are fine the way they are.